How can I rewrite this so that it does not repeat?
I'm looking for suggestions on how I could rewrite this so that the code isn't repeating. It's suppose to separate the float(digits) from the string(alphabetical characters) within a dictionary's value, and subtract or add a user's numerical input to the float. Afterwards, it rejoins the digits and the letters, converts them back into a string and stores the value.
An example of what it should do is take "19.0: chicken" from  the dictionary, split it, add 3  from the user's input, and return "22.0 chicken" to the dictionary.
if modify_options == "1":
    quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key]) [0]) + quantity
    quantity_measurement = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', str(inventory_list[key])))
    inventory_list[key] = str(quantity_value) + str(quantity_measurement)
    return inventory_list

elif modify_options == "2":
    quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key])[0]) - quantity
    quantity_measurement = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', str(inventory_list[key])))
    inventory_list[key] = str(quantity_value) + str(quantity_measurement)
    return inventory_list


Put the repeating code in a function. Seems the only thing different is quantity, which you can maybe think of as being positive or negative depending on modify_options, i.e. f 1 +quantity and if 2 +(-quantity)

quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key])[0]) + quantity *  (1 if modify_options=='1' else -1)

The best practice for this would be wrapping up the code within a function. Infact whenever you find some part of code is repeating multiple times, you are supposed to put it into a function.
Here's how to do it:
def update_inventory(key, option, quantity):
  quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key]) [0])
  quantity_measurement = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', str(inventory_list[key])))
  if option=="1":
   quantity_value += quantity
  elif option=="2":
    quantity_value -= quantity
  inventory_list[key] = str(quantity_value) + str(quantity_measurement)
  return inventory_list

#now you can update the inventory_list by calling the function 
update_inventory(2, "1", 9)
update_inventory(1, "2", 4)


It already is in a function, seeing as there are return statements.

That's true but the outer function is probably for some different purpose, there's nothing wrong to declare an update function seperately and use it inside function

If you are going to modify inventory_list in-place (either as a global variable or a function parameter), return None. Return a list if you are going to build a new list based on an argument.

You can refactor it in a couple steps. First, move the common statements outside of the if/else blocks.
if modify_options in {"1", "2"}:
    if modify_options == "1":
        quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key])[0]) + quantity
    elif modify_options == "2":
        quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key])[0]) - quantity

    quantity_measurement = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', str(inventory_list[key])))
    inventory_list[key] = str(quantity_value) + str(quantity_measurement)
    return inventory_list

Then you can move the common bit of the quantity_value statement up and only do the addition or subtraction inside the if/else.
if modify_options in {"1", "2"}:
    quantity_value = float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key])[0])
    if modify_options == "1":
        quantity_value += quantity
    elif modify_options == "2":
        quantity_value -= quantity

    quantity_measurement = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', str(inventory_list[key])))
    inventory_list[key] = str(quantity_value) + str(quantity_measurement)
    return inventory_list


The following should function using the operator module. Here's more about it.
import operator
import re

def code_snippet(modify_options, inventory_list, key, quantity):
    if modify_options == "1":
        option = operator.add
    elif modify_options == "2":
        option = operator.sub

    quantity_value = option(float(re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?", inventory_list[key])[0]), quantity)
    quantity_measurement = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z]', str(inventory_list[key])))
    inventory_list[key] = str(quantity_value) + str(quantity_measurement)
    return inventory_list


i find it overengineered using operator.add/sub

Surely @sahasrara62! Looking above, Malay Patra's solution is much more pythonic.

just my personal thought, nothing wrong with it, just personal opnion

You can create a method to perform this task and use one pattern to make it more efficient:
(?i)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*:?\s*([\w]+)\s*

Code
import re

def modify_inventory(inventories, key, quant, opts):
    print(inventories[key])
    q, m = re.findall(r"(?i)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*:?\s*([\w]+)\s*", inventories[key])[0]
    q = float(q)
    q = q + quant if opts == "1" else q - quant if opts == "2" else q
    inventories[key] = f"{q} {m}"
    return inventories


inventories = {
    'item1': '10.5 : potato',
    'item2': '20 : egg',
    'item3': '19.0 : chicken'
}

print(modify_inventory(inventories, 'item3', 3, '1'))
print(modify_inventory(inventories, 'item2', 3, '2'))


Prints
19.0 : chicken
{'item1': '10.5 : potato', 'item2': '20 : egg', 'item3': '22.0 chicken'}
20 : egg
{'item1': '10.5 : potato', 'item2': '17.0 egg', 'item3': '22.0 chicken'}

